# regex in awk to perform string manipulation

Tags: regex, awk

I have a line as below,

```
`string;{env=>{world=>is,always=>beautiful,gods=>grace}}`
```

I want to print to do some regex awk to print as below,

```
`string : env`
```

I can do it using cut to print "env" but not sure how to do print two strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this awk:

```
s='string;{env=>{world=>is,always=>beautiful,gods=>grace}}'
awk -F '[;{}=]+' '{print $1, ":", $2}' <<< "$s"

string : env
```

Comment: Not sure, but is the input JSON?

Comment: OP should answer that

Comment: Indeed, but if that is the case `jq` is the best tool I guess.. The requirement is met here anyways :-)

Comment: @sjsam That doesn't look like valid JSON to me.

Comment: @andlrc : From the basic examples I looked it didn't seem JSON to me too.. I felt a similarity though.

Comment: @anubhava Thanks! If I have multiple lines in the same format then I need to process it thru loop. Is there any better way to do this without using loop?

Comment: If you have it in a file then use: `awk -F '[;{}=]+' '{print $1, ":", $2}' file`